# Google Maps V3: Scaling a polyline relative to the map's zoom level?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, zooming, scale, polyline

In google maps api v3, is there a way to scale a polyline's stroke weight relative to the map's zoom level (similar to how a polygon acts on zoom)?

problem example: if I have the map at full zoom and draw a polyline on a road with the polyline's stroke weight set-up to match the width of the road, when I zoom the map out to display the city, the polyline's width (the road) appears to be roughly a mile wide.  Is there a way to keep the polyline the same size as the road would be when the map is zoomed?

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe that there is a built in method of scaling the strokeWeight so you may need to build your own. One method of doing this, just off the top of my head is to add an event listener to the map for the zoom_changed event and adjust the strokeWeight there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Phill, I figured that might be the case. Looks like I've got a night of messing with percentages ahead of me...